# Data Explorer KQL filtering and mapping JSONs in a list (dynamic type)

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to filter and transform JSONs in an array.

I have the following table:

```
let fooTable = datatable(str: string, record: dynamic) [
    "name1", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "B1"}]),
    "name2", dynamic([{"q": "bar", "type": "C1"}, {"q": "bar2", "type": "B1"}]),
    "name3", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "C1"}, {"q": "foo2", "type": "C1"}]),
    "name4", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "B1"}]),
    "name5", dynamic([{"q": "b42", "type": "B1"}]),
    "name6", dynamic([{"q": "f42", "type": "C1"}]),
    "name7", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "B1"}])
];
```

I want to filter the JSONs by "type" field, and do a minor transformation.
So let's say I want to filter with "type" "C1", so my output will be:

```
[
    "name2", dynamic([{"q": "bar", "type": "C1", "qtype": "barC1"}, {"q": "bar2", "type": "B1", "qtype": "bar2B1"}]),
    "name3", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "C1", "qtype": "fooC1"}, {"q": "foo2", "type": "C1", "qtype": "foo2C1"}]),
    "name6", dynamic([{"q": "f42", "type": "C1", "qtype": "f42C1"}
]
```

I tried the following:

```
fooTable
| mv-apply v=record on (
    where v.type == "C1"
    | extend r2 = pack(
        "q", v.q,
        "type", v.type,
        "qtype", strcat(v.q, v.type))
    | summarize record = make_list(r2)
    )
| project str, record
```

But if the type isn't "C1" it simply returns an empty array in the row:

```
name1   []
name2   [{"q":"bar","type":"C1","qtype":"barC1"}]
name3   [{"q":"foo","type":"C1","qtype":"fooC1"},{"q":"foo2","type":"C1","qtype":"foo2C1"}]
name4   []
name5   []
name6   [{"q":"f42","type":"C1","qtype":"f42C1"}]
name7   []
```

I want to filter these rows entirely (no empty rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

- first filtering on records that any of their members have `type` = `C1`
- then extending the record with the additional `qtype` property using the `bag_merge()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-merge-function

```
let fooTable = datatable(str: string, record: dynamic) [
    "name1", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "B1"}]),
    "name2", dynamic([{"q": "bar", "type": "C1"}, {"q": "bar2", "type": "B1"}]),
    "name3", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "C1"}, {"q": "foo2", "type": "C1"}]),
    "name4", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "B1"}]),
    "name5", dynamic([{"q": "b42", "type": "B1"}]),
    "name6", dynamic([{"q": "f42", "type": "C1"}]),
    "name7", dynamic([{"q": "foo", "type": "B1"}])
];
fooTable
| where tostring(record) has '"type":"C1"'
| mv-apply r = record on ( 
    extend record = bag_merge(r, pack("qtype", strcat(r.q, r.type)))
    | summarize record = make_list(record)
)
```